# Maximize Construct HD

Tags: pathfinder-1e, hit-points, constructs

I'm not looking to add HD to a construct, rather I'm wondering if it's possible to effectively maximize or increase the average added per HD.

Construct hit die are normally a d10, meaning average is 5.5, is there any way to increase this or even maximize it? I haven't found anything for this but perhaps there is an Adventure Path or niche book I'm not finding that has some rules.

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: @firedraco Pathfinder added the tag

Comment: Are you asking as a player in a game, in general RAW, or for some specific case?

Comment: In general RAW? I'm a player in the specific game this is relevant in @Ifusaso

Comment: Given the seeming dearth of official ways, would third-party *Pathfinder* material or  *3.5e* material also be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to beef up your constructs hit points without increasing its HD, something you may have overlooked (I believe this is in *Ultimate Magic*, based on the footer for the page on d20pfsrd, though I don't have a copy near me to check) is the [*Bioconstruct Modification*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs#TOC-Bioconstruct-Modification). This increases the CR by +1 and costs 22,750 GP per organ, of which there are 2 listed:

> - *Heart*: This upgrade permits a golem to receive half the benefits of magical healing and provides a hit point bonus as if the golem had a Constitution score of 12, but the construct does not gain a Constitution score in this process. Negative energy spells cast upon the golem can affect the heart, causing it to cease functioning for the duration of the effect (or 1 round for instantaneous effects). If the spell has a save, the heart uses the golem’s saving throws.
> - *Brain*: This upgrade doesn’t permit the golem to think independently, but instead, the brain works as a storage device, permitting the golem to acquire skills and feats as if it had an Intelligence score of 10. Enchantment spells or spells with mind-affecting effects that are cast upon the golem can affect the brain, causing the brain to cease functioning for the duration of the spell. While the brain is suppressed in this fashion, the construct temporarily loses access to its skills and feats. If the spell has a save, the brain uses the golem’s saving throws.

By adding the *heart*, your hit points are determined as if you had a 12 Constitution (so a +1 modifier), though you don't actual gain the Constitution score. The *brain* allows you to take skills and feats as if you had a 10 Intelligence, which allows you to take [*Toughness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/toughness-final/).

Adding the *Bioconstruct Modification*, in addition to the weaknesses listed in each organ comes with an additional weakness:

> All bioconstruct upgrades have the same weakness—they are susceptible to critical hits. An attacker that confirms a critical hit against a golem with a bioconstruct upgrade deals damage to the construct and also destroys one upgrade. The damaged upgrade ceases to function and the construct loses abilities associated with the upgrade. If a construct has more than one bioconstruct upgrade, only one is damaged. The GM randomly determines the damaged organ

Comment: From [Craft Construct](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-construct-item-creation/) "A newly created construct has average hit points for its Hit Dice."

Comment: Ah fair enough, looked at the creation rules, but not the actual feat that allowed creation